# Understanding the error operator representation $E = i^{\lambda}X(a)Z(b)$

Tags: error-correction, textbook-and-exercises, pauli-gates, pauli-group

Question regarding exercise $27.3.2$ in "Concise Encyclopedia of Coding Theory".

The exercise states:

> We write $E = X((0,1))Z((0,0))$ and $E' = iX((0,1))Z((1,1))$. We
> choose the ordering $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ of $\mathbb{F}_{2} ^{2}$
> and the corresponding ordering for the basis of $\mathbb{C}^{4}$.
>
> The Matrix for $X((0,1))$ agrees with $I_{2} \otimes \sigma_{x}$, the
> matrix for $Z((0,0))$ is $I_{4}$, and the matrix for $Z((1,1))$ is
> diagonal with diagonal entries $1,-1,-1,1$.
>
> Multiplying matrices confirms that $\sigma_{z} \otimes \sigma_{y}$ is
> indeed $iX((0,1))Z((1,1))$

Would someone be able to help me with understanding the notation?

My understanding is that an error operator $E_{i}$ can be defined as follows: $E_{i}:=i^{\lambda}X(a)Z(b)$ where $\lambda \in $ { $0,1,2,3$ } and $a,b$ are length $n$ binary vectors. Perhaps my understanding is wrong, I had previously thought that $X(a)$ was the Pauli gate $X$ acting on the vector $a$ and $Z(b)$ was the Pauli gate $Z$ acting on the vector $b$. Obviously this is wrong as the exercise uses $\sigma_{x}$ and $\sigma_{z}$ to denote the Pauli gates.

I also thing my understanding is wrong for the matrix $X((0,1))$ agreeing with $I_{2} \otimes \sigma_{x}$. I had thought that we obtained this because there is a $1$ in the second position of the vector and the $X$ is acting on it, hence $I_{2} \otimes \sigma_{x}$. Now, I think this is wrong. Instead $I_{2} \otimes \sigma_{x}$ is the following matrix- $$ I_{2} \otimes \sigma_{x} =\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
But I don't understand how we obtained this from $X((0,1))$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps my understanding is wrong, I had previously thought that $X(a)$ was the Pauli gate $X$ acting on the vector $a$ and $Z(b)$ was the Pauli gate $Z$ acting on the vector $b$.

Your understanding looks correct. Although the notation here is somewhat different than what I'm used to. It looks like with $I_2$ they mean the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, and not an identity operator on the second qubit. With your understanding the last sentence of the quotation makes sense:

> "Multiplying matrices confirms that $\sigma_{z} \otimes \sigma_{y}$ is indeed $iX((0,1))Z((1,1))$"

In this part of your question, I don't understand what you're exactly confused about. $X((0,1)) = X(2)$ in your notation which they denote as  $I_{2} \otimes \sigma_X$. You give the correct $4\times4$ matrix:

> Now, I think this is wrong. Instead $I_{2} \otimes \sigma_{x}$ is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$
> But I don't understand how we obtained this from $X((0,1))$?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Upon review, I finally understand where I was going wrong. I did not understand the representation of $E = i^{\lambda + \epsilon}X(a)Z(b)$.

I now understand that if $(a_{i},b_{i})=(1,0)$, this corresponds to $\sigma_{x}$ acting on qubit $i$. If $(a_{i},b_{i})=(0,1)$, this corresponds to $\sigma_{z}$ acting on qubit $i$. If $(a_{i}, b_{i})=i(1,1)$, this corresponds to $\sigma_{y}$ acting on qubit $i$.

Additionally $\epsilon$ is the number of $\sigma_{y}$s in $E$.

Additionally, I agree in this case that $I_{2}$ is referring to a $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.